# How to say "cheap and easy" for food/recipes?

Tags: word-choice

I am looking for recipes online in Japanese but I am not sure about some of the terminology. In particular, I'd like to search for "cheap and easy recipes" - are 簡単【かんたん】 and 安い【やすい】appropriate words for this purpose?

Thank you :)

Comment: 「安い」「簡単」「レシピ」でググってもいいし、「節約」「簡単」「レシピ」でググってもいいと思います

Comment: 安上がり{やすあがり} would meet your intension. But '節約' is the tag most often seen in cookpad like Shoko says.

Comment: That's great, I guess that's the word I was missing! Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes those are appropriate words but here are more choices for you.

similar words for easy

ー簡単（kantan)

ー手軽(tegaru)

ー時短(zitan/quick)

ー初心者(shyoshinshya/beginner)

Similar words for cheap

ー安い(yasui)

ー節約(setsuyaku)

ーコスパ(kosupa/cost-effective)

"ズボラ飯(zubora-meshi)" means super easy and quick meals.